# How to "reuse" registered objects in PhysX?

Tags: c++, physx

My issue is that I want to reuse objects in a scene.

Mainly I want to use the registered actor (in PhysX) with its data on another position, but not wanting to allocate new memory on the GPU.

I cannot figure out which links or pointers I have to set to reach my goal.

Does anyone have tips regarding this issue?
Is there any possibility to copy a PxActor?